# shiny dashboard selectizeInput and plots

Tags: r, plot, widget, shinydashboard

I'am trying to create a shiny application about the Tunisian elections, 
i put the political party as a widgets, so the user can choose one or multiple politicals parties and the application will show a plot of the number of votes of each political party, I have succeeded in the case of choosing one political party but when the user choose more than one, it failed :(
undermentioned the code R concerning the plot :

```
 selectizeInput("parti", label = "Parti politique", choices=  levels(data$Q99), selected = "Nidaa Tounes",multiple=TRUE)

 #server.R 
 library(shiny)
 library(Rcmdr)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(ggalt)
 data <-     readXL("C:/Users/boti/Desktop/regression/bfinal.xlsx",rownames=FALSE, header=TRUE, na="NA", sheet="imp", stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
dataa<-reactive({as.data.frame(data)}) 

#Parti politique
partii=reactive({
as.character(input$parti)
})
output$plot1=renderPlot({
n=as.data.frame(table(dataa()[,95]))
n$Var1[n$Var1==partii()]

ggplot(n, aes(x =n$Var1[n$Var1==as.list(partii())] , y = n$Freq[n$Var1==as.list(partii())])) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill="Orange") + labs(title="Vote") +labs(x="Partis Politiques", y="Nombre de votes")

})

})
```

Answer (score 0):

This example uses the mpg dataset to do what I guess you are trying to do. With the selectize input a user selects one or more manufacturers and the barplot displays the number of cars for the selected manufacturers:

ui.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
            titlePanel("Example"),
            fluidRow(
                    column(3, 
                           selectizeInput("mpgSelect", 
                                          label = "Select manufacturer", 
                                          choices = levels(as.factor(mpg$manufacturer)), 
                                          selected = "audi", 
                                          multiple=TRUE))),
            fluidRow(
                    mainPanel(plotOutput('coolplot'),width = '40%'))
    ))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
            mpgSubset <- reactive({
                    validate(
                            need(input$mpgSelect != "", 'Please choose at least one feature.')
                    )
                    filter(mpg, manufacturer %in% input$mpgSelect)
            })
            output$coolplot<-renderPlot({
                    gg <- ggplot(mpgSubset(), aes(x = manufacturer, y = ..count..))
                    gg <- gg + geom_bar()
                    print(gg)
            })
    })
```